# Debugging a Go process in a container using Delve/Goland from the host

Tags: docker, go, delve, goland

Before I burn hours trying it out I wanted to ask the community is this even possible?

Scenario:

- Running Goland on host (may be any OS)
- Running Go dev env in Alpine based container
- Code on host volume mapped to container

Can I attach the Goland debugger (Delve) to a Go process in the container? I'm assuming I can run delve in the container headless and run the client on the host, punching whatever port is required? Will I have binary compatibility issues if the host is not linux?

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather not duplicate the entire post in this answer, but have a look at this resource on how to use containers to run applications you write https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2018/04/30/debugging-containerized-go-applications/

To answer this specifically, as long as you have Go, the application sources, and all dependencies installed on the host machine, you can develop in GoLand and then, using a mapped volume, you can also run it from the container.

However, this workflow sounds more like the workflow you'd normally have using VMs not containers, which is why in the above article all the running/debugging is done using the actual containers, rather than using bash inside a container to run those commands.